# Find similar key-value elements from lists of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to find similar key-value items from two list of dicts and create a new dict which has these similar elements.

```
brod_dict = [

{'1877': [{'channel_id': '705',
             'code': '238'}]},
 {'4278': [{'channel_id': '490',
            'code': '352'}]},
 {'4389': [{'channel_id': '545',
            'code': '24'}]},
 {'5474': [{'channel_id': '191',
            'code': '179'},
           {'channel_id': '348',
            'code': '179'},
           {'channel_id': '387',
            'code': '340'}]},
 {'511': [{'channel_id': '453',
            'code': '380'}]},
 {'310': [{'channel_id': '246',
            'code': '24'}]}]
```

Where as the second dict is:

```
channel_dict = [

{'191': [{'brod_id': '5474',
           'code': '179'}]},
 {'246': [{'brod_id': '5730',
           'code': '24'}]},
 {'348': [{'brod_id': '5474',
           'code': '179'}]},
 {'387': [{'brod_id': '5474',
           'code': '340'}]},
 {'453': [{'brod_id': '4278',
           'code': '380'},
          {'brod_id': '5113',
           'code': '380'}]},
 {'490': [{'brod_id': '4278',
           'code': '352'}]},
 {'545': [{'brod_id': '4389',
           'code': '24'}]},
 {'705': [{'brod_id': '4278',
           'code': '238'},
          {'brod_id': '7170',
           'code': '238'}]}]
```

I am trying to create a third dict which has the same `brod_id` and `channel_id` and a list which only has the `brod_id` of the discared keys.

```
result_dict = [
{'490': [{'brod_id': '4278',
           'code': '352'}]},
{'545': [{'brod_id': '4389',
           'code': '24'}]},
{'191': [{'brod_id': '5474',
           'code': '179'}]}]
```

and the list output:

```
result_discarded = ['1877', '511', '310']
```

What I tried:

```
for d1, d2 in zip(brod_dict, channel_dict):
    for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(d1.items(), d2.items()):
        if k in channel_dict.values():  # not the right way
            print(channel_dict[k2])
```

Sorry, I am still learning python so if i made any obvious mistakes

Comment: `brod_dict` and `channel_dict` are lists of dicts of lists of dicts. Maybe you can simplify that structure a bit before working with them? Then I think your question becomes one that is easier to solve and has answers on SO :)
PS: Is it intentional that the dicts in `brod_dict` contain `channel_id`s and vice versa?

Comment: @DavidWierichs yes, the intentionally have the `channel_id`s in the `brod_dict`. I dont think i can change the structure, as this is a smaller chunk of a bigger problem.

Comment: On what basis are you including the 191...5474 pairing in the output but not including the 348...5474 or the 387...5474?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a fairly inconvenient format for the data, and the following approach starts by simplifying the input format a bit before attempting to process it, although the result is then produced directly in the specified format.

Note that I have changed the variable names for the inputs and outputs to use a `_list` suffix rather than `_dict`, because they are not dictionaries.

This:

```
from pprint import pprint   # for pretty-printing the output

brod_list = [
    {'1877': [{'channel_id': '705',
               'code': '238'}]},
    {'4278': [{'channel_id': '490',
               'code': '352'}]},
    {'4389': [{'channel_id': '545',
               'code': '24'}]},
    {'5474': [{'channel_id': '191',
               'code': '179'},
              {'channel_id': '348',
               'code': '179'},
              {'channel_id': '387',
               'code': '340'}]},
    {'511': [{'channel_id': '453',
              'code': '380'}]},
    {'310': [{'channel_id': '246',
              'code': '24'}]}]

channel_list = [
    {'191': [{'brod_id': '5474',
              'code': '179'}]},
    {'246': [{'brod_id': '5730',
              'code': '24'}]},
    {'348': [{'brod_id': '5474',
              'code': '179'}]},
    {'387': [{'brod_id': '5474',
              'code': '340'}]},
    {'453': [{'brod_id': '4278',
              'code': '380'},
             {'brod_id': '5113',
              'code': '380'}]},
    {'490': [{'brod_id': '4278',
              'code': '352'}]},
    {'545': [{'brod_id': '4389',
              'code': '24'}]},
    {'705': [{'brod_id': '4278',
              'code': '238'},
             {'brod_id': '7170',
              'code': '238'}]}]

result_list = []

def list_of_dicts_to_dict(lst):
    return dict([next(iter(d.items())) for d in lst])

# pre-processing

brod_d = list_of_dicts_to_dict(brod_list)
chan_d = list_of_dicts_to_dict(channel_list)

#=============================
# To process these, build up two sets of (brod_id, chan_id, code) tuples,
# one based on each of the inputs, and look for the intersection of these
# sets.

set1 = set()
set2 = set()

for brod_id, chans in brod_d.items():
    for chan in chans:
        chan_id = chan['channel_id']
        code = chan['code']
        set1.add((brod_id, chan_id, code))
        
for chan_id, brods in chan_d.items():
    for brod in brods:
        brod_id = brod['brod_id']
        code = brod['code']
        set2.add((brod_id, chan_id, code))

used_brod_ids = set()
for brod_id, chan_id, code in set1 & set2:
    used_brod_ids.add(brod_id)
    result_list.append({chan_id: [{'brod_id': brod_id,
                                   'code': code}]})

all_brod_ids = set(brod_d.keys())
result_discarded = list(all_brod_ids - used_brod_ids)

pprint(result_list)
print("\ndiscarded:")
pprint(result_discarded)


#=============================
##  Original version of processing - left here commented out, and would 
##  replace everything between the lines of "#=====" above.  This method
##  looks simpler because it has fewer lines of code, but it has three 
##  nested loops instead of two, so it would scale more poorly.
##
##  (Does not calculate result_discarded)
#
# for brod_id, chans in brod_d.items():
#    for chan in chans:
#        chan_id = chan['channel_id']
#        for brod in chan_d[chan_id]:
#            if brod['brod_id'] == brod_id:
#                code = chan['code']
#                if code == brod['code']:
#                    result_list.append({chan_id: [{'brod_id': brod_id,
#                                                   'code': code}]})
#=============================
```

gives this output:

```
[{'545': [{'brod_id': '4389', 'code': '24'}]},
 {'191': [{'brod_id': '5474', 'code': '179'}]},
 {'348': [{'brod_id': '5474', 'code': '179'}]},
 {'387': [{'brod_id': '5474', 'code': '340'}]},
 {'490': [{'brod_id': '4278', 'code': '352'}]}]

discarded:
['511', '1877', '310']
```

Note that the output is in no particular order, because it is implemented using sets.

It is not exactly the output specified in the question, but it is not clear on what basis the `348` and `387` should be excluded if the `191` is included.

Comment: Now edited to give the more efficient solution as the main one, with the alternative method left in as comment lines.

Comment: Awesome, could you also add the `list` that has the `brod_id`s that are not included? i.e. `['1877', '511', '310']`

Comment: @CookieMonster Ah, good point, I forgot that bit of the question, I'll have a look now.

Comment: @CookieMonster Now done. Again, in no particular order, because I've used sets to calculate it. (One could sort the result if wanted.)

Comment: @CookieMonster You'll see that in that case I used subtraction on sets, meaning the elements of the set `all_brod_ids` that are not present in the set `used_brod_ids`.

Comment: Just a quickie, If I add more elements in the dict, i.e. apart from channel_id and code, lets say there is another element called pickup_id, that changes the result? is it because its looking for an intersection that includes the new element too?

Comment: @CookieMonster Well you could make an n-element tuple containing all the things you want to put in it. Just make sure you use the same ordering of tuple elements in both sets. And also be aware that anything you put into a set needs to be a hashable object, so don't try changing those tuples into dictionaries because that wouldn't work.

Comment: I commented out the original sets in the loops and added more elements. If you uncomment those you get a different result

Comment: @CookieMonster I haven't looked in detail, but just to be clear what it's doing, _all_ the elements in those tuples have to match between what is obtained from the two input lists. If they don't all match, then the whole thing is not considered a match.

Comment: What if I want elements outside the match? lets say I only want to match two elements and the rest I need to print?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! :D

Comment: @CookieMonster In that case, you have a little bit more work, but you could make a dictionary that maps `tuple_of_stuff_you_want_to_match` to `extra_stuff_you_want_to_print`. You only add `tuple_of_stuff_you_want_to_match` to your sets, but then when you are looping over the elements in the intersection of the sets, you then use that dictionary to look up `extra_stuff_you_want_to_print`. Now `extra_stuff_you_want_to_print` doesn't need to be a hashable object so you could use a dictionary if you prefer that to a tuple. (Elements of a set and **keys** of a dictionary need to be hashable.)

Answer (score 0):

The if-statement has to be `if k in v2.values():`. `channel_dict` is actually a list in your case, `channel_dict.values()` is thus not correct since `values()` is a function for dictionaries.

Comment: I figured that out. thanks but it doesn't help much